# Why doesn't my redirect work for /?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this redirect at the top of routes.rb

```
constraints subdomain: 'www' do
  get ':any', to: redirect(subdomain: nil)
end
```

It works for everything except for "/".

So, it works for `www.example.com/foo` -> `example.com/foo`, but it doesn't work for `www.example.com/`.

Comment: I don't know _why_, but I do know that you can add `root to: redirect(subdomain: nil)` inside the block for the same effect.

Comment: that worked! feel free to submit as an answer. if someone comes along with the _why_ one day then we will be enlightened. but i am happy dying in ignorant bliss, with a functioning redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but for the same effect add `root to: redirect(subdomain: nil)` inside the block. Hopefully someone smarter than me can answer as to why `*path` isn't matched to `/`